# How to create a database file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

How to create a database file in python.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection(r"C:\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db")
```

Comment: And does your current code work?  If not, what error do you get?  What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection(r"C:\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db")
```